# CHANGE IN WSDL AND ERROR IN SOAPUI PROJECT

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I created a Soap Project for a group of soap web services in my test region where i can run the project repeatedly just by changing input data/test data(here my wsdl was updated in September in Testregion).

Now,my test region has got an Wsdl Updated(september wsdl does not exists in test now) and when i try to run soap project(built using sep wsdl).its giving
me below error

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org   /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://konnex.aarp.org/types/SwordCiboodleServicesSecure" env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <env:Body>
          <env:Fault>
               <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
               <faultstring>JAXRPC.TIE.04: Internal Server Error   (JAXRPCTIE01: caught exception while handling request: java.lang.NullPointerException)</faultstring>
          </env:Fault>
     </env:Body>
  </env:Envelope>
```

SO my question is is there any way to use/run the same project with new updated WSDL

Comment: @Rao Sir, Please help me clarifying on this topic

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SoapUI then there is an option to update WSDL definitions by right clicking on the WSDL you imported and choosing update definition. From your description the option "Recreate existing requests with new schema" sounds like what you want.

The following link gives a description of what the options are and example situations for using them https://dzone.com/articles/soapui-tip-options-refreshing

Comment: I am using soap sonar

Comment: Pls let me know if Anybody knows about soap sonar